# Tem como espaçar dois textos em centímetros em uma mesma célula do Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Conforme o exemplo da figura abaixo. eu preciso tabular em uma única célula dois textos de forma que de uma célula para a outra (da mesma coluna) os textos da direita fiquem perfeitamente alinhados (veja a coluna D).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na parte superior da figura: exemplo do resultado que tenho com o desalinhamento dos números das páginas (coluna D).

Na parte inferior: o mesmo trecho, mas com as fórmulas aplicadas.

Na célula D2 está informado o número de espaços da distância em caracteres que o segundo texto deveria ficar alinhado. Aqui o ideal é que fossem "centímetros" ou algo assim e não espaços.

Sei que existem inúmeras formas simples para fazer isso, como usar duas colunas ou uma fonte com caracteres de mesmo tamanho em pixels, mas no meu caso eu preciso resolver assim, em uma única célula e com uma fonte qualquer que se queira aplicar.

Este procedimento deve ser adicionado a uma planilha complexa que manipula dinamicamente um relatório que tem vínculos com várias outras planilhas e funcionalidades. O tratamento do texto é dinâmico, ou seja, se marco um tópico ou desmarco, toda o relatório é ajustado automaticamente, os números dos tópicos são modificados e as páginas em que são apresentados podem ser alteradas também. Por exemplo, um tópico "4. CUSTOS" que está na página 34, dependo do que for feito, pode virar o tópico "6. CUSTOS" e constar da página 59, e são inúmeros itens, com tópicos e subtópicos. O tamanho das células e suas colunas, preferencialmente não devem ser modificados.

Tentei algumas formas para obter o resultado, pesquisei, mas sem sucesso.

Caso tenha como fazer, ainda que seja complexo, deverá ser melhor e mais rápido que estudar e reestruturar esta planilha.

Agradeço desde já as colaborações ou comentários.

Comment: Não há como fazer isso apenas no Excel porque ele não tem uma fórmula ou função que calcule o comprimento em pixels de um texto qualquer na fonte utilizada. Talvez seja possível você implementar uma função de cálculo do comprimento em pixels em C++, construir uma DLL e então utilizá-la no Excel... mas eu acho que você está tentando resolver um problema que não é um problema: como vc mesmo disse, há outras formas de fazer (e eu acho que são melhores). A melhor delas? Use duas colunas separadas. Aliás, o Excel existe pra isso: pra manipular dados **tabulados**.

Comment: Oi Luiz, entendo, mas como os textos nos subtópicos são longos, e a largura para impressão está no limite desejado, no momento abrir uma nova coluna não resolve, eu já havia tentado, mais afeta várias outras partes.Estou tentando lidar com este detalhe sem ter de manipular o restante que é bem complexo. Legal a dica do C++, é uma boa possibilidade.

Comment: Cara, eu não entendi por que não resolve. O limite da impressão depende dos comprimentos das colunas, claro, mas se você adicionar uma nova basta reduzir o comprimento da coluna anterior (até porque, ela já não tem mais o conteúdo que você colocou na nova coluna). Enfim, era só uma sugestão, porque eu acho que esse caminho que vc tá querendo seguir é muuuuiiiiitooo difícil (ao ponto de talvez ser melhor implementar isso em outra ferramenta/linguagem).

Comment: Oi Luiz, você está certo, mas pode ser que exista uma solução, estou adiantando outras partes e depois voltarei ao problema, se não tiver uma forma alternativa de fazer, terei um árduo trabalho pela frente, mas isso faz parte... Valeu mesmo assim, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que apresento não é exatamente como gostaria, mas resolveu o problema de forma simples e direta.

Adicionei um `TextBox` (controle ActiveX) no final e sobre cada linha da página inicial que pode ter texto a referenciar a página (com o mesmo espacejamento em quantidade de linhas no meu caso, entre os controles).

Nas propriedades passei para transparente, alinhei todos e alterei a fonte para a mesma ativa no Excel (pois acredito que não há como fazer isso automaticamente, reconhecer a fonte da célula *linkada*), após isso, agrupei tudo para poder ajustar o bloco para os lados com facilidade para quando for o caso.

Na propriedade **LinkedCell** apontei para a célula com o texto do número da página a ser apresentado.

Com isso, as linhas que apresentam número de página têm sues `TextBox` atualizadas dinamicamente, assim como as demais ficam "vazias" e não aparecem quando não apresentam número de página.

**Veja o exemplo abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na primeira linha destaquei a `TextBox`que cada linha tem no final, assim como nas duas últimas linhas, para mostrar que todas estão lá, as outras linhas aparecem como devem aparecer para impressão (os controles também estão lá). Por serem transparentes e não terem texto, na verdade as duas linhas finais aparecem "em branco" como devem aparecer, aqui destaquei para exemplificar melhor.

É isso!

Comment: Por que o espaçamento funciona no TextBox e não funciona na célula? Vc diz que "alterou a fonte". Para qual? Curioso que na sua pergunta vc dizia "e com uma fonte qualquer que se queira aplicar". (me ocorreu agora que você talvez adicionou TextBox **apenas para os números de linha**, no lado direito das colunas de texto; se for isso, explique melhor - com ilustrações - pois não está devidamente claro).

Comment: Oi Luiz, não fiz o espaçamento no TextBox, apenas o coloquei no final da linha, assim na impressão aparece o número da página como se estivesse originalmente na célula impressa, é apenas sobreposição. Vou rever a resposta.

Comment: Luiz, veja se ficou bom agora...